# How to evaluate a causal model?

Tags: causality, graphical-model, bayesian-network, model-evaluation

Say I am responsible for reducing crime rate in an area and I build a causal graphical model for the local crime rate. Assume I can only conduct observational study. How do I evaluate my model?

Comment: First see if you can justify the claim that there are no variables correlated with your independent variables and affect your criterion that are not in the model.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test a large model of causal relationships, you can use structural equation modeling to do so. One output of a SEM is the overall model goodness of fit; if it fits well, this is evidence that your causal model is adequate. To make a real causal claim, though, you must do the theoretical work of including confounders sufficient to identify a causal effect for each causal relationship you propose. You can this relationship-by-relationship using common causal methods like instrumental variables or matching.